# mongodb issue when using .find()

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, vue.js, mongoose

I am using MongoDB for the first time and I came across an error that I could not solve.

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('../../common/services/mongoose.service').mongoose;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const functions = require('./functions');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    number: String,
    state: Boolean
});

userSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

// Ensure virtual fields are serialised.
userSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});

userSchema.findById = function (cb) {
    return this.model('Users').find({id: this.id}, cb);
};

const User = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);


exports.findByEmail = (email) => {
    //console.log('hello'); //this works btw
    return User.find({email: email});
};
```

So in the code above, findByEmail works fine since hello is logged. However, when it gets to return User.find, I get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0.

This is what is currently in the DB:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6026b813f1828a51f8979616"),
        "email" : "gogo@gmail.com",
        "password" : "GLImDln1xMKfKS/E99s8qg==$Es3PIHD95vV89973Xq4RecveYMEf22PCH/pFtG1+xq4Gtc4DelA/JXlRNcOR11Rfv/J1uaZCuOplsEmHhY0ehQ==",
        "number" : "6969",
        "state" : true,
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I input gogo@gmail.com. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? It would mean a lot to me. I am using node/vue btw.

**Error occurs within findByEmail when I run it**

Comment: Where does the error occurr? Please edit your question to include that code.

Comment: @cbr added it. It occurs within findByEmail

Comment: Show the code that calls `findByEmail`.

Comment: You would need to show us how you call the `findByEmail` module. Where does that happen? Also, while you're at it, replace your `console.log('hello');` with `console.log("email:", email);` and see what you get.